# Maxima of symmetric functions in $\frac{1}{x},x$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, maxima-minima, maximum-likelihood

Is it true that Maxima/Minima of symmetric polynomial functions in $x,\frac{1}{x}$ lies when $x=\frac{1}{x}$,

For example,

$$x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}$$
Has it's Minima at $x=1$

We may also write$$f(x)=\sum_{r} k(x^r+x^{-r})$$

Is it also true when $x$ is complex, for eg. Maxima of $$|x+\frac{1}{x}|$$

Comment: Yes, but it might have a maximum for something like $$2-(x+\frac{1}{x})$$

Comment: Oh ok, sorry for that

Comment: I think it's pretty obvious to me now, if you find $f'(x)$ you get that at $x=1$ ,$f'(x)=0$

Comment: But the complex question still remains

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to construct examples of such functions that do not have extrema at $x = \pm 1$. For instance, by exploiting the continuous function
$$
g(x) = \cases{0 & if $x = 0$\\x\sin(1/x) & otherwise}
$$
This function doesn't behave nicely around $x = 0$. We can move that non-nice behaviour to $x = \pm 1$ by considering, for instance, $g(|x| - 1)$. Then make it symmetric with respect to $x\mapsto 1/x$ by simply adding another copy with $1/x$ in place of $x$. The final result is
$$
f(x) = g(|x| - 1) + g\left(\left|\frac1x\right| - 1\right)
$$
and this does not have extreme values at $x = \pm 1$.

Comment: Hey, i think your answer is great, but i have just updated the question, will you check the updates